# How can I dynamically add and change divs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function timeMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("enterquestion()",900000);
}


function enterquestion()
{
document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += '<p>'  + document.getElementById("question").value;


}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Testing Website</h1>
<p id="questions"></p>

<input type="text" name="question" id="question" />
<button type="button" onclick="timeMsg()">Enter question</button>


</body>
</html>
```

All this code does is it allows the user to enter a question and then it adds the question to the list of questions after 15 minutes have passed.

All I'd like to do to the code is make it so that it immediately puts the text "QUESTION RECORDED" in the place where the question will show up, then instead of simply adding the question to the end, it should replace the "QUESTION RECORDED" text with the question.

I can't figure out how to do it in such a way that you can enter multiple questions at the same time.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Um, call the function on the button click?

Answer (score 0):

The innerHTML property is handy when you want to replace the entire content of an element but not for adding or inserting child nodes. For that, it's easier to use [createElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-2141741547).

The following is an example to get you going:

```
<script>
function addDiv(parent, text) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  parent.appendChild(div);
}
</script>

<form action="serverprocess" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="text" name="qText" value="Question text">
  <button onclick="
    addDiv(document.getElementById('container'), this.form.qText.value);
  ">Add question</button>
</form>
<div id="container"></div>
```

In the above, if javascript isn't available or active, the form will be submitted and processing can be done on the server. If it's available, then it will be processed locally and the form won't submit, though submission should really be based on successful completion of the actions.

I'll leave that for you to ponder.